# Is my sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

"If you were an adult, would you do the same?"

Firstly, I don't quite understand "were" here. Maybe "was" is needed here, because "you" is a singular noun?

Secondly, why we use would? Why not "will"?

Also, if my sentences sound quite weird, feel free to correct me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your sentence doesn't make sense. Do you mean "If I were you"? And no, "you" always takes the plural form (are/were rather than is/was).

Comment: Corrected my sentence. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence is correct without considering any special context.
The sentence is implying that it is being told to a child/teenager; someone who is not adult at the moment.
The use of the word "would" is not wrong. The sentence is talking about a situation that does not exist and we're thinking about it hypothetically.